# New mesh seems to move unrelated mesh

Tags: transforms

I have created a character's head in 2.8, and I wanted to add a cube. I did so, but when I move the cube down the z axis, it also moves the character's head, even if the only thing I've selected is the cube.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image: an]

I can move the cube by itself in edit mode, but I used to be able to do so in object mode.

Answer (score 1):

I had proportional editing on. I didn't realize that had any effect in object mode!